# Neater way for a JavaScript if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Ok, I know this is a mess. This is why I'm posting it here. I hope you can understand the logic that I am trying to create. Is there a nicer way to make this happen?

```
else if (((!(lc(this).getByIndex(i).dim2.Shirts)) && ('Nike' in lc(this).getByIndex(i).dim3)) 
    || (('Nike' in lc(this).getByIndex(i).dim3) && ('Shirts' in lc(this).getByIndex(i).dim2)))
```

There are basically two statements here: I want this statement to prove true if Shirts AND Nike are present OR Nike but no category at all. Hope that helps, but I will move this over to code review, but will wait for a solid answer so someone gets the cred :) ... Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: you want the contents of your if-statement re-factored?

Comment: maybe you can reformat your code

Comment: Can you post an explanation of what the code is trying to do? Perhaps there's a better way (that already exists), instead of refactoring the if statement.

Comment: Is that PHP? Or something else? Show the ***JavaScript***, not the server-side script that generates it.

Comment: Thanks I just added the explanation. I'm running in to an unexpected identifier as well. Hoping that something a little easier to read will help me find the other issue.

Comment: Ok, so I updated my answer. Note you can access shirts through the dot notation (dim2.Shirts), but also through the Square brackets [ ]!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on GitaarLAB's answer, how about this?

```
...
else {
    var x      = lc(this).getByIndex(i),
        y      = x.dim2.Shirts,
        nike   = 'Nike'   in x.dim3,
        shirts = 'Shirts' in x.dim2;

    if (!y && nike || nike && shirts) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you could do:

```
else {
  //comparisons
  var a=yadayadayada,
      b=blablabla,
      c=1024,
      d=document.getElementById('something').value;
      //and so on
  if( a===b || c<=d ){ //that should keep your if-clause a lot more readable!!
    //actions
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE** (after TS update):
Now we know a little more about your data and you ask: '*true if Shirts AND Nike are present OR Nike but no category at all*', then this is what you want:

```
else {
  var b='Nike', //brand
      c='Shirts', //category
      d=lc(this).getByIndex(i),
     d2=d.dim2,
     d3=d.dim3;
  if( ((b in d2) && d2[c]) || (b in d2) ){ 
    //actions
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have "Nike...etc." in both statements, you can shrink it to:

```
else if ( ('Nike' in lc(this).getByIndex(i).dim3)
  && (!lc(this).getByIndex(i).dim2.Shirts || ('Shirts' in lc(this).getByIndex(i).dim2)) )
```